# How do I set the <link> in an html file using c#?

Tags: c#, html

My program creates html files.  I recently starting using css files to simplify how much code I'm writing to the files.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(MyFile))
{
    sw.WriteLine("<head>");
    sw.WriteLine("\t<title>My Project</title>");
    sw.WriteLine("\t<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"../config/MyStyleSheet.css\">");
    sw.WriteLine("</head>");
}
```

When the file is created the  link looks like this:

```
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=MyStyleSheet.css>
```

When I copy the link address of the MyStyleSheet.css link it has a path that is the same as where the html file exists.

When I manually create an html file and type this exact line in:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../config/MyStyleSheet.css">
```

it works perfectly.  What can I do to get c# to add this line correctly?

Comment: What is strange (to me at least) is that quotes also seem to be dropped by your wtreamwriter...

Comment: Not just the quotes, but also `../config/` too.  Something definitely isn't right here - are you sure this is all the relevant code?

Comment: You may try using a verbatim string literal by placing the @ symbol in front of the string @"stringhere" you will no longer be required to escape characters this way.  Not an answer just a tip.

Comment: @JamesThorpe, I left off the <html> tag but I figured you all would assume that.

Comment: @MichaelHumelsine, I have tried that as well.  That doesn't work either.

Comment: What are you using to view the generated HTML?

Comment: I just noticed that the `<link>` tag doesn't have a closing `>` in your code, could be causing some wierdness in the browser

Comment: @JamesThorpe, Just updated it in the code above and in my code, still getting the same issue.  Good catch though!

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, I'm using notepad++.

Comment: @JamesThorpe, and yes, I'm also viewing source in Chrome.

Comment: Is `MyFile` a path to a file, or an already open Stream that may be doing something wierd with what you're passing it?

Comment: @JamesThorpe, it's a file path.  "C:\users\userid\Alpha\alphacode.html"

Comment: Should there be a trailing backslash after "../config/MyStyleSheet.css".

Comment: @KyleT Yes, it's escaping the quotes that mark the end of the attribute

Comment: @JamesThorpe That makes sense now.

Comment: You could try escaping the attributes with single quotes? like this "\t<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../config/MyStyleSheet.css'>"

Comment: @KyleT, just tried that.  Same issue.

Comment: @KyleT,  The html file is in: C:\users\userid\Alpha

Comment: @KyleT, the css is in C:\users\userid\Config

Comment: When I copy and paste the link address from the MyStyleSheet.ccs (from within Chrome) it gives me, file:///C:/users/userid/Alpha/MyStyleSheet.css

Comment: The above code is fine. Your issue is somewhere else.

Comment: After I re-installed the IDE all is good now.